# How to precise the Perl version when creating a package using conda-build

Tags: linux, perl, package, conda, conda-build

I am trying to create a package for a Perl module I have and then put it in a local channel to be able to install it in a conda environement. I am trying to follow the conda documentation but as it's the first time I'm trying to do that, I kind of lost myself.

Doc to create a conda package from scratch : https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html

Doc to understand the metadata of a meta.yaml file : https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#build-section

Doc to conda-build : https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-build.html

So first I created a recipe with a meta.yaml file and a build.sh file. The version of Perl included in my conda is 5.26.2. However the Perl module has been written with Perl 5.18.2. I can't find a way to modify the version of Perl...

I tried to :

```
$ conda-build <path_to_perl_module>/recipe --perl=5.18.2
```

I also tried to put in the meta.yaml file some specifications for Perl in the requirements section.

```
requirements:
  host:
    perl >=5.18.2
```

But in both cases (I also tried to change the run/build section of the requirements with the same result) when I install the package in a conda environment, the console prompt :

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pmp-0.8.2_BSP              |                0           5 KB  file:///home/usr/BSP-channel
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:           5 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  libgcc-ng          pkgs/main/linux-64::libgcc-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0
  perl               conda-forge/linux-64::perl-5.26.2-h516909a_1006
  pmp                BSP-channel/linux-64::pmp-0.8.2_BSP-0
```

As you can see, the package manager wants to install Perl 5.26.2. I guess I don't do it the right way but the documentation doesn't really help me or I haven't found the corresponding part.

Any leads would be greatly appreciate.

Have a good day/night !

**edit :**
What Could I do ?

1. Use my local Perl located in usr/bin/Perl ?
2. Download the Perl 5.18.2 package from : https://www.cpan.org/src/README.html and linked it somehow inside the meta.yaml file ?

Comment: Does your module not work with Perl 5.26? If so, why do your requirements say `>=5.18.2` instead of just `5.18.2` or `5.18.*`?

Comment: The module is not supported yet for Perl 5.26.2.
If I only `perl 5.18.2` or `perl 5.18.*` I got this error message when trying to build the package : `conda_build.exceptions.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform linux-64: set(['perl=5.18.2'])
`

Comment: I don't know where conda is pulling packages from. Maybe they don't have a package for perl 5.18.2?

Comment: Well the Perl I am using outside conda is under `usr/bin/perl` and it's the good version. I haven't found a way to linked locally my Perl inside the meta.yaml file. Could it be possible ? --- I have another option in mind which would be to download the Perl 5.18.2 package and put it in my local channel and precise in the meta.yaml to use this package as Perl but if it's possible I don't really know what could be the steps to follow.

Comment: No idea; I hadn't even heard of conda before this question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my issue. I'm not sure it's the right way to do though.

I download the conda package for Perl 5.18.2 here : https://anaconda.org/Nersc/perl/files

I also indicate in the meta.yaml in the requirements field :

```
requirements:
  run:
    perl x.x
```

I put the package in my custom channel. Then I create the package using `conda-build <path_to_Perl_module>/recipe/ --perl=5.18.2`. When I install the package using `conda instal <perl_module>` I get this output :

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    perl-5.18.2                |                3        14.2 MB  file:///home/usr/BSP-channel
    pmp-0.8.2_BSP              |                0           5 KB  file:///home/usr/BSP-channel
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        14.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  perl               BSP-channel/linux-64::perl-5.18.2-3
  pmp                BSP-channel/linux-64::pmp-0.8.2_BSP-0
```

If I create the module without indicating `--perl=5.18.2` we then look for the newest Perl version available in conda-forge.

I hope it will help you if you are stuck with the same issue.